# programe mis contenido en un pantalla mdpi de 3,2" y me doy cuenta que hay otra de 5.1" mdpi y su contenido se ve pequeño?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-asynctask, android-fragment

programe el contenido de mi app para un pantalla mdpi de 3.2" y se ajusta bien , pero al cambiar el modo de vista a una de 5.1" mdpi esta no se ajusta, ayuda con este problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3.2" mdpi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
5.1" mdpi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto es totalmente natural puesto que si ambas están en MDPI, las imágenes no se agrandan ni se achican. Generalmente los dispositivos (en el mercado) con más pulgadas, tendrán mayor densidad a MDPI y por lo tanto no habrá problema y se verán bien. En el ejemplo que muestras en Android Studio sería un caso extremo.

Sin embargo si quisieras cambiar el tamaño, ancho, alto o padding y márgenes puedes crear carpetas para las dimensiones:

```
values-xlarge
values-large
values-small
values-normal
```

En cada carpeta tendrías un archivo `dimens.xml` con tamaños como por ejemplo:

```
<dimen name="ancho_imagen">48dp</dimen>
```

Y en otra carpeta otro tamaño, las equivalencias son las siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo si la pantalla es de 5 pulgadas se usará la medida (tamanño o valor) que esta en la carpeta `values-large`.

Así se usaría el valor en cualquier `View` por ejemplo:

```
android:layout_width="@dimen/ancho_imagen"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sinceramente se ve muy bien el layout. Nunca se van a ver los elementos exactamente igual en todos los dispositivos.

Ademas, gracias a trabajar en dps y no en tamaños relativos a la pantalla con escalado, se puede aprobechar una pantalla grande.

Saludos.

Comment: y para escalar en tabletas